# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "en capilla ardiente"?

Tags: modismos

Soy de Guatemala y he escuchado muchas veces la expresión *"en capilla ardiente"* principalmente cuando una persona está a punto de contraer nupcias se le dice ***"estas en capilla ardiente"***.

Me parece bastante curiosa la expresión por lo que quisiera saber el verdadero significado de la misma.

Answer (score 4):

Parece que es una mezcla de "estar en capilla" con "capilla ardiente". Según la RAE:

> [**capilla.**](http://dle.rae.es/capilla)
>   (Del lat. *cappella, dim. de cappa, capa).
>   [...]
>   **~ ardiente.**
>   1. (Por estar alumbrada con muchas luces). f. La de la iglesia en que se levanta el túmulo y se celebran honras solemnes por algún difunto.
>   2. f. Oratorio fúnebre provisional donde se celebran las primeras exequias por una persona, en la misma casa en que ha fallecido.
>   3. f. Cámara donde se vela un cadáver o se le tributan honras.
>
> [...]
>   **estar en ~, o en la ~.**
>   1. locs. verbs. Dicho de un reo: Estar desde que se le notifica la sentencia de muerte hasta la ejecución, en cualquier pieza de la cárcel dispuesta como capilla.
>   2. locs. verbs. coloqs. Dicho de otra persona: Hallarse en el trance de pasar una prueba o de conocer el resultado de algo que le preocupa.

Así que yo diría que es una variación de "estar en capilla", significando más o menos "a la espera de un desenlace afortunado" (la [wikipedia da este significado](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capilla)).

Lo de añadir "ardiente" tal vez sea en tono humorístico, de igual forma que en ocasiones se da el pésame a quien va a casarse.

Comment: En mi opinión, se utiliza —a manera de broma— en el sentido del condenado que espera su ejecución, y se dice sobre todo en los últimos días/horas antes de la boda. También he escuchado que únicamente se le dice tal cosa al novio, nunca he escuchado que se le diga a una novia.